# C# - Application freezing suddenly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am actually making a game, the issue is that when a card moves (I'm using Timer), it makes me freeze the entire form, sometimes it manages to load, sometimes it freezes the entire game. (+ prevents from clicking a label and clicking a MessageBox)

Issue : (.png)

[Here](https://prnt.sc/u2d5x6)

Code :  (timers)

```
public void moveCardsAdv6_2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Partie)
        {
            Distrib = true;
            int y6_2 = 48;
            int x6_2 = 13;

            pictureBoxd6_2.Top += y6_2;
            pictureBoxd6_2.Left += x6_2;

            #region Adversaire 6
            if (pictureBoxd6_2.Top >= 560 && pictureBoxd6_2.Left >= 110)
            {
                dist6_1 = true;
                SecondDistr = true;
                moveCardsAdv6_2.Stop();
                pictureBoxd6_2.Location = pictureBoxDeck.Location;
                GenCartesAdv();
                dist6_1 = false;
                SecondDistr = false;
                moveCardsAdv7_2.Enabled = true;
                moveCardsAdv7_2.Start();
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Card gen code

```
#region Adversaire 6
int CarteAleaA6 = CarteAleatoire();
Cartes carteA6 = jeu[CarteAleaA6];
CartesUtilisees.Add(CarteAleaA6);
int CarteAleaA6_2 = CarteAleatoire();

while (CartesUtilisees.Contains(CarteAleaA6_2))
{
    CarteAleaA6_2 = CarteAleatoire();
}

CarteAleaA6_2 = 1 * CarteAleaA6_2;

ListeCartes.Add(carteA6);

if (Distrib && dist6_1)
{
            if (SecondDistr == false)
            {
                pictureBoxAdv6_1.ImageLocation = carteA6.Image;
            }
            else
            {
                Cartes carteA6_2 = jeu[CarteAleaA6_2];
                CartesUtilisees.Add(CarteAleaA6_2);
                ListeCartes.Add(carteA6_2);
                pictureBoxAdv6_2.ImageLocation = carteA6_2.Image;
            }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: FYI, setting the `Enabled` property to `true` is the same thing as calling the `Start()` method for the `Timer` class. You don't need to do both.

Comment: I always run my Ticks on worker threads.  Helps smooth things out and worker threads are fairly easy to implement.

Comment: The root cause is likely just what @EllieK is getting at - maybe you are doing too much work on the main UI thread, causing the UI to be unresponsive.  You could look at the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) and [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

As the others suggested, maybe try moving them into asnyc functions and await them.

```
        public async void moveCardsAdv6_2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await moveCardsAdv6_2_TickAsync();
    }

    private async Task moveCardsAdv6_2_TickAsync()
    {
        if (Partie)
        {
            Distrib = true;
            int y6_2 = 48;
            int x6_2 = 13;

            pictureBoxd6_2.Top += y6_2;
            pictureBoxd6_2.Left += x6_2;

            #region Adversaire 6

            if (pictureBoxd6_2.Top >= 560 && pictureBoxd6_2.Left >= 110)
            {
                dist6_1 = true;
                SecondDistr = true;
                moveCardsAdv6_2.Stop();
                pictureBoxd6_2.Location = pictureBoxDeck.Location;
                GenCartesAdv();
                dist6_1 = false;
                SecondDistr = false;
                moveCardsAdv7_2.Enabled = true;
                moveCardsAdv7_2.Start();
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```